# How to make a shape with left-top round rounded corner and left-bottom rounded corner?

Tags: android, android-shape

I want to make a shape with with left-top rounded corner and left-bottom rounded corner:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
    <solid android:color="#555555"/>    

    <stroke android:width="3dp"
            android:color="#555555"
            />

    <padding android:left="1dp"
             android:top="1dp"
             android:right="1dp"
             android:bottom="1dp"
             /> 

    <corners android:bottomRightRadius="0dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="2dp" 
     android:topLeftRadius="2dp" android:topRightRadius="0dp"/> 
</shape>
```

But the shape above didn't give me what I want. It gives me a rectangle without any rounded corners.

Answer (score 73):

It looks like a bug http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=939.

Finally I have to write something like this:

```
 <stroke android:width="3dp"
         android:color="#555555"
         />

 <padding android:left="1dp"
          android:top="1dp"
          android:right="1dp"
          android:bottom="1dp"
          /> 

 <corners android:radius="1dp"
  android:bottomRightRadius="2dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp" 
  android:topLeftRadius="2dp" android:topRightRadius="0dp"/>
```

I have to specify android:bottomRightRadius="2dp" for left-bottom rounded corner (another bug here).

Comment: Yes, I can confirm your last statement/bug that left/right is switched there. I experienced the same in my app as well. (sdk 2.1). Did you file a bug report on b.android.com already for it or is it reported there already?

Comment: I just filed a bug, http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9161.
The sad thing is, after they fix the bug, I have to change my code again :(

Answer (score 58):

While this question has been answered already (it's a bug that causes bottomLeftRadius and bottomRightRadius to be reversed), the bug has been fixed in android 3.1 (api level 12 - tested on the emulator).

So to make sure your drawables look correct on all platforms, you should put "corrected" versions of the drawables (i.e. where bottom left/right radii are actually correct in the xml) in the res/drawable-v12 folder of your app. This way all devices using an android version >= 12 will use the correct drawable files, while devices using older versions of android will use the "workaround" drawables that are located in the res/drawables folder.

Comment: Another option is to use a default `values/dimens.xml` file that contains the inverted bottom_left and bottom_right values, and a new `values-v12/dimens.xml` file that has the *correct* values.  That way you can keep just a single version of the drawable XML file, and only the dimen value is swapped based on the API version.

Answer (score 36):

From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html):

> **NOTE:** Every corner must (initially) be provided a corner radius greater than 1, or else no corners are rounded. If you want specific
>   corners to not be rounded, a work-around is to use android:radius to
>   set a default corner radius greater than 1, but then override each and
>   every corner with the values you really want, providing zero ("0dp")
>   where you don't want rounded corners.

E.g. you have to set an `android:radius="<bigger than 1dp>"` to be able to do what you want:

```
<corners 
    android:radius="2dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="0dp" 
    android:topRightRadius="0dp"/>
```

Answer (score 15):

You can also use extremely small numbers for your radius'.

```
<corners 
  android:bottomRightRadius="0.1dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="2dp" 
 android:topLeftRadius="2dp" android:topRightRadius="0.1dp" />
```

Comment: that was the first i tried... but no hope.... i'm testing on Android 2.2... Any other ideas... Thanks

Answer (score 12):

for others there are a solution for any API level , you can place a item on top of each other example :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<!-- my firt item with 4 corners radius(8dp)
 -->
    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid
                android:angle="270.0"
                android:color="#3D689A" />

            <corners android:topLeftRadius="8dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
<!-- my second item is on top right for a fake corner radius(0dp)
 -->
    <item
        android:bottom="30dp"
        android:left="50dp">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#5C83AF" />
        </shape>
    </item>
<!-- my third item is on bottom left for a fake corner radius(0dp)
 -->
    <item
        android:right="50dp"
        android:top="30dp">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#5C83AF" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

the result with light color to show you the three items :

[image]

the final result :

[image]

Best regards.

Answer (score 8):

This bug is filed [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9161).
This is a bug of android devices having API level less than 12.
You've to put correct versions of your layouts in drawable-v12 folder which will be used for API level 12 or higher.
And an erroneous version(corners switched/reversed) of the same layout will be put in the default drawable folder which will be used by the devices having API level less than 12.

For example: I had to design a button with rounded corner at bottom-right.

**In 'drawable' folder - button.xml:** I had to make bottom-left corner rounded.

```
<shape>
    <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="15dp"/>
</shape>
```

**In 'drawable-v12' folder - button.xml:** Correct version of the layout was placed here to be used for API level 12 or higher.

```
<shape>
    <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="15dp"/>
</shape>
```

Answer (score 8):

try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid android:color="@color/upkia"/>
<corners android:radius="10dp"
    android:topRightRadius="0dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="0dp" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
        android:radius="@dimen/dimen_5dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="0dp" />
</shape>
```

[image: Achived this]