# Android: Shape "corners" problem. Is this a bug?

Tags: android, rounded-corners, shapes

I was playing with corners, and I was intrigued with this behavior. XML layout:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
    android:id="@+id/list_header_title"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"

    android:background="@layout/my_outline"

    android:text="Example"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" 

/>
```

This is my_outline.xml: **(pay attention to the corners tag)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

<corners
        android:topLeftRadius="10dip"
        android:bottomRightRadius="10dip"/>

<padding
        android:left="50dip"
        android:top="5dip"
        android:bottom="5dip" />

<solid
        android:color="#0fff" />

<stroke
        android:width="1dip"
        android:color="#f0f0f0" />

</shape>
```

Picture:

[image]

Change the shape to:

```
<corners
        android:topLeftRadius="10dip"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="10dip"/>
```

And you can clearly see that the bottom corners are inverted (happens with all, i cut "Wednesday" just to illustrate). This is a picture of my phone (Nexus S 2.3.2, but happens on the emulator as well):

[image]

Are you aware of this? I looked at Google ("android shape inverted corner"), and got nothing. Here on SO there are no "related questions" as well.

Comment: I Faced the same problem !! And i think its a Bug.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yup, it's a noted bug. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4379478/comical-bug-in-android-xml-shape-declaration/4379516#4379516) for more links and reference info. :P

Comment: Ah, ok. Sorry about that, I didn't see the questions. Probably the system didn't pick them up by the words. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, no problem, the related questions aren't always that accurate, and sometimes it's hard to find stuff like this. (I just knew it cause I answered in that question, haha). Tricky bug though, because if they fix it, I would think it would break all the apps that already work around it...

Comment: That's a point. I, for myself, already did just that. Perhaps one day they may deprecate this and use some other name. Or... maybe not.