# android:bottomRightRadius is actually left?

Tags: android, xml

I'm using a simple drawable rectacngle with opposite corners rounded as a android:background.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:shape="rectangle"> 
    <solid 
        android:color="@android:color/white" 
    />
    <corners 
        android:radius="1dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="0dp"
        android:topRightRadius="40dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="40dp"
    />
</shape>
```

I fill a little bit dissapointed. Is it OK?

Comment: This probably will answer your question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3056232/how-to-make-a-shape-with-left-top-round-rounded-corner-and-left-bottom-rounded-co

Comment: This is a known bug. See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6003382/224248

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep. There is a known issue. See this question:
[How can I work around Android issue 9161, where bottomRightRadius and bottomLeftRadius are swapped?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003382/how-can-i-work-around-android-issue-9161-where-bottomrightradius-and-bottomleftr)