# Custom button drawable corners bottom left, bottom right differed in 2.3.3 and 4.0 (4.0 is showing right)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable

[image]

above screen displays what is my error is... in 4.0 it works fine but in 2.3.3 my drawable works not good..
**bottom_right_drawable.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true"><shape>
            <solid android:color="#d4972c" />

            <corners android:bottomRightRadius="10dp" />

            <stroke android:width="0.5dp" android:color="#0a627f" />
        </shape></item>
    <item android:state_pressed="false"><shape>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />

            <corners android:bottomRightRadius="10dp" />

            <stroke android:width="0.5dp" android:color="#0a627f" />
        </shape></item>

</selector>
```

I don't know why it acts like this, I have tried, How can I get drawable similar working as 4.0? and why it is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.
I have created values-v12 folder and put dimens.xml with left_button_left and left_button_right values for left button and this values also place in values>dimens.xml with flipped number to left to right and right to left, same way for right button..
and placed in drawable, `<corners android:bottomLeftRadius="@dimen/left_button_left" android:bottomRightRadius="@dimen/left_button_right" />` and it works great for me... thanks to [This link for same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12505649/somethings-wrong-in-corner-radius-android?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

I think I faced this problem before, and I solved it using more than one `Shape`
1- for 2.3
2- for 4.0

you can do that by creating a folder in res named `drawable-v10` thats will be for 2.3
and put the **modified (fixed)**  version of your `Shape`
and in `drawable` folder put your current `Shape` that will be used in 4.0

Comment: after adding drawable-10 and changes according to right drawable to left and left to right, in 2.3.3 works but now in 4.0 it creates problem as in 2.3.3. and current drawable is in 'drawable' folder for 4.0

Comment: you have your current shape in the `drawable` folder, not the `drawable-v10`?

Comment: @Ridcully I said the **modified** shape, not the original one

Comment: I thought the question was, how to modify the shape so it works. So the answer to say use the modified shape and it will work deemed me not very helpful.

Comment: Yes, My original shape is in drawable folder. But because some bug before 3.0, I need to change that drawable shape for displaying same in all os device. (Want to get output of bottom right corner in all device)