# Different button shape

Tags: android, xml

I am giving a custom shape to a `Button`. The xml file which is used as `background` for `Button` is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
<solid android:color="#2E8B57" />

<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="20dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="0dp"
    android:topRightRadius="20dp" />

</shape>
```

I am using fragments in the application. The B`enter code here`utton which uses this `drawable` displays the expected behavior in tablet, but when viewed in a phone, the display changes. These are the screenshots of tablet and phone:

[image]
[image]

As can be seen, in the tablet view, `Buttons` are rounded from topright and bottomright, but not from topleft and bottomleft (which is what I want). However in phone, the topright and bottomleft are rounded. Am I missing something ?

Comment: Work on real device, emulator usually shows wrong layouts for shapes

Comment: @GokhanArik: I tried on a real devices. The results are similar on tablet and phone as seen on respective emulators.

Comment: Ok then this might be helpful : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12505649/somethings-wrong-in-corner-radius-android

Comment: Yes it was a bug, sorry I didn't pay attention to your question at first. I remember after checking.