# Android Button Style Background with XML

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

So I have two button styled pretty close to what i want but i need a little help getting it all the way. What I currently have is the first screen show, what I want is the second. Anyone have any ideas? I've attached the relevant code.

[image]
[image]

layout xml:

```
....
<Button
            android:id="@+id/sched_button"
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/sync"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@drawable/round_left_corner_active"
            android:text="@string/headersched"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/placeholder"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/scheduleheadermargin"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/scheduleheadermargin" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/sched_fav_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/sched_button"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/placeholder"
            android:background="@drawable/round_right_corner"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/scheduleheadermargin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/scheduleheadermargin"
            android:text="@string/headerfav" />
...
```

round_left_corner_active:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="@color/active" />

            <padding
                android:bottom="2dp"
                android:left="2dp"
                android:top="2dp" />

            <corners android:radius="5dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <padding
                android:bottom="5dp"
                android:left="5dp"
                android:right="5dp"
                android:top="5dp" />

            <solid android:color="@color/active" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

round_right_corner

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="@color/active" />

            <padding
                android:bottom="2dp"
                android:right="2dp"
                android:top="2dp" />

            <corners android:radius="5dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <padding
                android:bottom="5dp"
                android:left="5dp"
                android:right="5dp"
                android:top="5dp" />

            <solid android:color="@color/base" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the left button:

```
<corners
    android:radius="5dip"
    android:topRightRadius="0dip"
    android:bottomRightRadius="0dip" />
```

And the right one:

```
<corners
    android:radius="5dip"
    android:topLeftRadius="0dip"
    android:bottomLeftRadius="0dip" />
```

This should do the trick.

However, `android:bottomRightRadius` and `android:bottomLeftRadius` have a bug in API lower than 12 (Android 3.1 Honeycomb). You should set the radius inside `dimens.xml` and create a new folder `values-v12`. See this solution: [Something's wrong in Corner radius](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12505649/somethings-wrong-in-corner-radius-android/12505934#12505934).
Then, you should do:

**drawable button left**

```
... 
<corners
    android:radius="5dip"
    android:topRightRadius="0dip"
    android:bottomRightRadius="@dimen/right_bottom_leftbutton"
    android:bottomLeftRadius="@dimen/left_bottom_leftbutton" />
```

**drawable button right**

```
... 
<corners
    android:radius="5dip"
    android:topLeftRadius="0dip"
    android:bottomRightRadius="@dimen/right_bottom_rightbutton"
    android:bottomLeftRadius="@dimen/left_bottom_rightbutton" />
```

**values/dimens.xml**

```
<!-- left button -->
<dimen name="right_bottom_leftbutton">5dip</dimen>
<dimen name="left_bottom_leftbutton">0dip</dimen>
<!-- right button -->
<dimen name="right_bottom_rightbutton">5dip</dimen>
<dimen name="left_bottom_rightbutton">0dip</dimen>
```

**values-v12/dimens.xml**

```
<!-- left button -->
<dimen name="right_bottom_leftbutton">0dip</dimen>
<dimen name="left_bottom_leftbutton">5dip</dimen>
<!-- right button -->
<dimen name="right_bottom_rightbutton">5dip</dimen>
<dimen name="left_bottom_rightbutton">0dip</dimen>
```

Comment: Perfect... and i'll look into that bug in 3.1 what Sdk Version is that?

Comment: @jcaruso Android 3.1 Honeycomb (API level 12). Thanks for pointing me this stupid mistake, I'll correct it.

Comment: What stupid mistake is that? I'm only targeting `minSdkVersion="14"` so i wouldn't need it correct?

Comment: @jcaruso It's API 12 and SDK version 3.1. I wrote the inverse (API 3.1... that's a beautiful mistake) ;)

Comment: If you have the min version to 14, you don't need to set the values inside dimens file, just use the first codes. However, I'll let my complete answer for other users, it might help someone who wants the same behaviour in lower api. @jcaruso

Comment: Great call, i'm sure someone else will find this very useful.