# parent layout corners not visible because selector overlaps

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-tabs, android-selector

Im tryng to build tabs using rounded linearlayout which has 2 textviews.

**I want the following output**

[image]

**What happens instead is the following**

[image]

The selector applied to textview gets drawn on top of parent layouts drawable, because of which the corners are not visible. I cannot add corners to textview selector because it will round all 4 corners in each textview.

I also thought of using specific corners i.e shaping each textview, but tht will increase number of drawables for each textview, which is not a flexible solution, in future I may choose to use more tabs.

Please can anyone suggest a generic xml solution so that I can change the background of textviews without affecting parent layout corners?

**My Code**
**Layout**

```xml
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/layout_background"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/issue_tab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/tab_selector"
        android:fontFamily="@raw/roboto_medium"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="TAB 1" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#4c8bff" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/activity_tab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/tab_selector"
        android:fontFamily="@raw/roboto_medium"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="TAB 2" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**layout_background.xml**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:dither="true"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#4c8bff"/>
    <corners android:radius="5dp" />
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFFFF" />

</shape>
```

**tab_selector.xml**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected"/>
 <!-- selected -->
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_pressed"/>
 <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_pressed"/>
 <!-- focused -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/tab_normal"/>
 <!-- default -->    
</selector>
```

**tab_selected.xml**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <solid android:color="#4c8bff" />
</shape>
```

Comment: Can you post the image of output you're getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated Code**

Create tab_selected_left_corner.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <solid android:color="#4c8bff" />
    <corners
       android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
       android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
       android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
       android:topRightRadius="0dp" />
</shape>
```

Create tab_selected_right_corner.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <solid android:color="#4c8bff" />
    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="0dp"
        android:topRightRadius="5dp" />
</shape>
```

Create layout_background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:dither="true"
android:shape="rectangle" >

<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="#4c8bff" />

<corners android:radius="5dp" />

<solid android:color="#FFFFFFFF" />

</shape>
```

#### Your main xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/layout_background"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/issue_tab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:text="TAB 1" />

<View
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#4c8bff" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/activity_tab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:text="TAB 2" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Put this in your `activity`

```
issueTab.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            issueTab.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_selected_left_corner);
              activity_tab.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.transparent);
        }
    });
    activity_tab.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
              issueTab.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.transparent);
            activity_tab.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_selected_right_corner);
        }
    });
```

This works for me.. Hope for you also.

Comment: it does same thing, except that, it does rounding on all 4 corners of textview which looks bad near divider line at center of layout, plus the unselected tab does not get its border because of the overlap

Answer (score 0):

**@Sulabh Gajjar** - Thanks a ton for such a detailed answer. I had this approach in mind but I was wondering if there could be a better way, so kept this as my last option.
Like you suggested, created 2 selectors for left and right tabs, instead of creating new drawables, I wrote shapes inside selector itself and created 2 separate files to store different corner radius as suggested by https://stackoverflow.com/a/12952591/1020809. Currently its working for me, but I'll wait few more days incase someone comes up with a more generic way, if nobody shows up, I'll mark your answer as accepted. Thanks again... :)

Using your approach, here's what I did to get it running

**Layout**

```xml
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_tab_background"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/issue_tab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_tab_selector_left"
        android:fontFamily="@raw/roboto_bold"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="Issues"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="@color/custom_tab_text_color_selector"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <!--
         <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/custom_tab_selected" />
    -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/activity_tab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_tab_selector_right"
        android:fontFamily="@raw/roboto_bold"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="Activities"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="@color/custom_tab_text_color_selector"
        android:textSize="14sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**custom_tab_background.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:dither="true"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="@color/custom_tab_selected" />

    <corners android:radius="5dp" />

    <solid android:color="#FFFFFFFF" />

    <padding
        android:bottom="2dp"
        android:left="2dp"
        android:right="2dp"
        android:top="2dp" />

</shape>
```

**dimens.xml**

```
  <dimen name="custom_tab_layout_radius">4dp</dimen>
```

**custom_tab_selector_left.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_selected="true">
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <solid android:color="@color/custom_tab_selected" />
            <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="@dimen/custom_left_tab_bottomLeftRadius" 
                android:bottomRightRadius="@dimen/custom_left_tab_bottomRightRadius" 
                android:topLeftRadius="@dimen/custom_left_tab_topLeftRadius" 
                android:topRightRadius="@dimen/custom_left_tab_topRightRadius" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <!-- selected -->

    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <solid android:color="@color/custom_tab_pressed" />
            <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="@dimen/custom_left_tab_bottomLeftRadius" 
                android:bottomRightRadius="@dimen/custom_left_tab_bottomRightRadius" 
                android:topLeftRadius="@dimen/custom_left_tab_topLeftRadius" 
                android:topRightRadius="@dimen/custom_left_tab_topRightRadius" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <!-- pressed -->

    <item android:state_focused="true">
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <solid android:color="@color/custom_tab_pressed" />
            <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="@dimen/custom_left_tab_bottomLeftRadius" 
                android:bottomRightRadius="@dimen/custom_left_tab_bottomRightRadius" 
                android:topLeftRadius="@dimen/custom_left_tab_topLeftRadius" 
                android:topRightRadius="@dimen/custom_left_tab_topRightRadius" />
        </shape>       
    </item>
    <!-- focused -->

    <item>
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <solid android:color="@color/custom_tab_normal" />
            <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="@dimen/custom_left_tab_bottomLeftRadius" 
                android:bottomRightRadius="@dimen/custom_left_tab_bottomRightRadius" 
                android:topLeftRadius="@dimen/custom_left_tab_topLeftRadius" 
                android:topRightRadius="@dimen/custom_left_tab_topRightRadius" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <!-- default -->

</selector>
```

**/res/values/custom_tab_corners.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- LEFTMOST TAB -->
    <dimen name="custom_left_tab_topLeftRadius">@dimen/custom_tab_layout_radius</dimen>
    <dimen name="custom_left_tab_bottomLeftRadius">0dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="custom_left_tab_topRightRadius">0dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="custom_left_tab_bottomRightRadius">@dimen/custom_tab_layout_radius</dimen>

    <!-- RIGHTMOST TAB -->
    <dimen name="custom_right_tab_topLeftRadius">0dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="custom_right_tab_bottomLeftRadius">@dimen/custom_tab_layout_radius</dimen>
    <dimen name="custom_right_tab_topRightRadius">@dimen/custom_tab_layout_radius</dimen>
    <dimen name="custom_right_tab_bottomRightRadius">0dp</dimen>    
</resources>
```

**/res/values-v12/custom_tab_corners.xml**

```
<resources>
    <!-- LEFTMOST TAB -->
    <dimen name="custom_left_tab_topLeftRadius">@dimen/custom_tab_layout_radius</dimen>
    <dimen name="custom_left_tab_bottomLeftRadius">@dimen/custom_tab_layout_radius</dimen>
    <dimen name="custom_left_tab_topRightRadius">0dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="custom_left_tab_bottomRightRadius">0dp</dimen>

    <!-- RIGHTMOST TAB -->
    <dimen name="custom_right_tab_topLeftRadius">0dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="custom_right_tab_bottomLeftRadius">0dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="custom_right_tab_topRightRadius">@dimen/custom_tab_layout_radius</dimen>
    <dimen name="custom_right_tab_bottomRightRadius">@dimen/custom_tab_layout_radius</dimen>    
</resources>
```