# How to define a android drawable folder

Tags: android, android-layout, directory, resolution, hdpi

Refering to this Question: [How to make a shape with left-top round rounded corner and left-bottom rounded corner?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3056232/how-to-make-a-shape-with-left-top-round-rounded-corner-and-left-bottom-rounded-c?lq=1) I have just created a new Drawable folder called `res\drawable-v12` in my android project. In this way I want all devices using an android version >= 12  to use `res\drawable-v12` folder. Do I need to define it some where so the devices will use `drawable-v12` folder?

Answer (score 1):

nope. as long as you've got the right file structure `res/drawable-v12` it'll be just fine.